# Is there a linguistic term for the phrases, which describe a noun, with subjective value (below)

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

a pitted excuse for a road
a big bear of a man
a gigantic furious beast of a man
a wisp of a boy/girl

Comment: Separate from the question, I believe you're intending "pitiful excuse" in the first example

Answer (score 2):

Each one is an example of a type of a [metaphor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metaphor) defined by the Cambridge online dictionary as

> an expression, often found in literature, that describes a person or object by referring to something that is considered to have similar characteristics to that person or object:

Metaphors often, but not always, have this "A (something) of (something else)" structure but can have other structures such as "(something) is a (something else)". An example of that type of metaphor from the linked dictionary entry is "The city is a jungle". That's obviously not literally true, cities and jungles are two different things, but the metaphor presents the comparison as though it were a fact.

This is as opposed to a [simile](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simile) which is defined by the same dictionary as

> (the use of) an expression comparing one thing with another, always including the words "as" or "like":

For instance if your second example had been "A man like a big bear" rather than "A big bear of a man" that would have been a simile since the comparison is made explicit by the use of the word "like" whereas in a metaphor the comparison is concealed by the metaphor looking like a statement of literal fact.

Answer (score 0):

"A pitted excuse for a road" occurs as a common collocation with "excuse" - "an **excuse {for** (in place of) something}" and is not a comparator.

"Noun1 of a noun2" is also not a comparator. It is a standard use of "of + substantive" which produces a prepositional modifier. It has been in English since at least the 12th century:

OED

> **Of** *(prep.)*
>
> **23. Between two nouns which are in virtual apposition. b. In the form of, in the guise of.**
>
> *The leading noun is the latter, to which the preceding noun with of stands as a qualification, equivalent to an adjective; thus ‘that fool of a man’ = that foolish man, that man who deserves to be called ‘fool’; ‘that beast of a place’ = that beastly place.*
>
> [c1175   Ormulum (Burchfield transcript) l. 11695   *Þeȝȝ hallȝhenn cristess flæsh off bræd & cristess blod teȝȝ hallȝhenn. Off win.]*
>
> 1956   I. Murdoch Flight from Enchanter xii. 176   *‘You beastly contemptible shit of a crook,’ said Hunter.*
>
> 1992   Vanity Fair (N.Y.) Feb. 144/3   *The Schramsberg offers a whirlwind of a mousse, tasting of lemon and yeast.*